# Save Tool Window position globally across projects in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I have my Tool Windows in specific parts of the screen (e.g. `Version Control` and `Terminal` occupying half of the bottom part) but every time I open a different project with IntelliJ the window positions are back to the default ones. It also opens windows I don't usually use (e.g. `Ant Build`).

Is there a way to save those settings globally and not per project?

Comment: i also have the same need.. which was satisfied in Eclipse with Save Perspective As...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `Window > Store Current Layout as Default` and `Window > Restore Default Layout` options seem to work, with the extra step of having to  `Restore Default Layout` once whenever I first open a new project.

[Intellij Docs Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html)

Comment: It partially works. It restores the position of the windows and and rearrange the order of the icons in the side bar but it doesn't remove icons from the sidebar. Also it doesn't appear to split my bottom part.. Is it a bug or is it the expected behaviour?

Comment: Good question - it might be worth filing an issue on JetBrains' issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=Restore%20Default%20Layout

Comment: Ok, perfect. Accepting this answer as it is better than nothing :)

Comment: doesn't seem like this exists anymore in 2024. The only otions now are to store as a custom layout, `store current as defualt` is no longer there